# Mysql - How to query 2 tables and output 1 row from tableA and associate multiple rows from TableB?

Tags: mysql

I need to select all the records from one column in a table, then associate those records to selected records of a column in a second table where a column in the second table is using a foreign key to the first table, then output the results.

TableA called “tblfilm” -  has a list (rows) of many films (example below):

```
Wizard of OZ

Gone with the Wind ... etc.
```

TableB called “tblfilmimage” has a list of many images (example below):

```
Wizard of Oz Image1

Wizard of Oz Image2

Wizard of Oz Image3 ...etc.

Gone with the Wind Image1

Gone with the Wind Image2 ... etc.
```

The two tables look like this:

tblfilm:

```
filmID
film
```

tblfilmimage:

```
imageID
image
filmID
```

So each table has the key filmID.

My current mysql statement is:

```
SELECT film, image
FROM tblfilm, tblfilmimage
WHERE tblfilm.filmID = tblfilmimage.filmID
```

A simple query that does NOT render the output desired, i.e. the query lists each film row with each of the films associated images (unintended result below):

```
Wizard of Oz        Image1
Wizard of Oz        Image2
Wizard of Oz        Image3

Gone with the Wind  Image1
Gone with the Wind  Image2
```

The desired output of the query is to list the film only once, then display each image associated with the film (desired output below):

```
Wizard of OZ        Wizard of Oz Image1
                    Wizard of Oz Image2
                    Wizard of Oz Image3

Gone with the Wind  Gone with the Wind Image1
                    Gone with the Wind Image2
```

... and so on with hundreds of films and multiple images associated with each film.

A solution for preventing multiple instances of the “film” records from being displayed in the output, using JOIN & GROUP BY / MAX(CASE END), was suggested in a separate thread (which worked), but requires knowing and coding the ImageID for every image that is associated with a film.

Every film has at least one image to associate. Most films have many and a varying number of images associated with the film. But the images associated with each film are unique to one film. Thus I need a way to first iterate through every film and then find all the images associated with each film via the (filmID) which is a common field to each table.

I think I will need a variable to store each film and a way to associate that film variable with a variable that stores all of the different images that have the same filmID as the film. So far I have been unable to figure a mysql statement that will do that.

Any comments or suggestions are welcome. Or anyone who wants to point me in the right direction with an example link so I can learn how to do this, that would be appreciated too. Thank you.

UPDATE: In re: to the suggestion that this requirement would be better handled using PHP (which I agree), I wrote the following snippet of PHP code:

```
//prepare and get result of query

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT film, image
                       FROM tblfilm, tblfilmimage
                       WHERE tblfilm.filmID = tblfilmimage.filmID");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

//fetch result and display film, then image

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<b>Film:</b> {$row['film']} <br><br>
{$row['image']} <br><br>";
}
```

But just like in my original question, I'm not sure how to prevent the film row from displaying with each image, in this case when using PHP code. I'm still pretty new to MySQL & PHP, so any pointers appreciated. My apologies if this updated question should have been moved to a new thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement should generally be handled in your presentation layer, e.g. PHP.  If you are using MySQL 8+, then we can approximate the output you want using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT f.film, i.image,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY f.film ORDER BY i.image) rn,
    FROM tblfilm f
    INNER JOIN tblfilmimage i
        ON f.filmID = i.filmID
)

SELECT
    CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN film ELSE '' END AS film,
    image
FROM cte t
ORDER BY
    t.film,
    rn,
    image;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Thank you Tim. I see what you mean about handling this within PHP. I may update this thread to ask a question re: that, if it's appropriate. It looks like my LAMP host is running MySQL v5.6.44 :-( Thank you for this example using ROW_NUMBER though.

Comment: OK, I updated my original post with a followup PHP question. My apologies if this followup question should have been moved to a different thread. Any advice on a PHP solution appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @obcbeatle If you want to output an HTML table, I can make a suggestion, otherwise you might want to open a new question.

Comment: Thank you Tim. I would take any suggestions re: output using an HTML. In fact, after giving this some more thought I think a table that is displayed via mysql/php that is sortable by the user would be nice, i.e. the user could sort by field once the table is displayed. For example sort by year, genre, etc. This solution would require a user submitted (link clicked) table sort depending on which field in the table they clicked. I'm currently reading about this trying to find a safe way to allow this type of sort to happen. I'm trying to find some simple examples. Anyway, probably a new topic.

Answer (score 1):

I din get the last statement but made it as assumed in the below query. Is this what you want?

```
       Select f.film, f.film||GROUP_CONCAT 
       (i.image  
       SEPARATOR',') from tblfilm f join 
          tblfilmimage i on f.filmid=i.filmid
        group by f.film having 
         filmid,count(i.image)
         IN Select 1,3 from((Select 
             filmid,imageid,count(*) 
           from filmimage group by 
           filmid,imageid))
```